# Passing null reference to overloaded constructor

Tags: vb.net, oop

Suppose that I have some class, "Foo" that has a couple of constructor overloads like so:

```
Class Foo
    Public Sub New(id as Integer)
        ' Do stuff here
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(fee as Fee)
        ' assume that Fee is some other type
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now, suppose that sometimes I just don't care about the value of id or fee, and I simply want to call the 2nd constructor and pass it a null reference.  In C#, I can do this with no problem by:

```
var foo = new Foo(null);
```

and it works as intended.  The VB equivalent of this would seem to be:

```
Dim foo as New Foo(Nothing)
```

although I know that technically, `Nothing` is equivalent to `default<T>`, so there is no direct equivalent.  Where I am getting hung up is here: the VB compiler can't seem to infer if `Nothing` should be an Integer or a Foo in this case, so it is throwing an error about ambiguity.  Is there any way to achieve the result I want, or is this a limitation of the language where I simply have to write a 3rd constructor or declare a dummy `Foo` variable, set it to `Nothing` and pass that to the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DirectCast` to tell compiler exactly what you're trying to achieve here:

```
Dim foo as New Foo(DirectCast(Nothing, Fee))
```

Comment: Ahhh, didn't think to cast `Nothing`.  Excellent suggestion and I think that it will work for what I am trying to do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Nothing` in VB.Net is essentially both `null` and `default(T)`.  It is the universal lack of a value expression.  You get an ambiguity error here because it works equally well for `Fee` and `Integer` types.

You can remove the ambiguity with a `DirectCast` expression

```
Dim foo As New Foo(DirectCast(Nothing, Fee))
```

The other option is to use an `Optional` value

```
Public Sub New(Optional ByVal fee As Fee = Nothing)
```

Then you can remove the ambiguity by just having the empty argument constructor

```
Dim foo As New Foo()
```

Comment: +1 for the most detailed explanation, MarcinJuraszek was just a little faster so I am marking his as the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can force it to call the correct overload by explicitly specifying the type, like this:

```
Dim foo As New Foo(DirectCast(Nothing, Fee))
```

However, if it is going to be a common occurrence, you may want to add another overload for the constructor:

```
Class Foo
    Public Sub New()  ' <- New overload
        ' Do stuff here
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(id As Integer)
        ' Do stuff here
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(fee As Fee)
        ' assume that Fee is some other type
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks Steven.  I am trying to limit the number of ctor overloads so I prefer the first option better.  And I saw you try to sneak CType in there  :P

Comment: Ha! Yes, the `CType` was short-lived :)  Coming from a c/c# background, I originally gravitated to `CType`, but I've been trying to remember to use `DirectCast` when more appropriate.  I had a short lapse, there :)